# Location file within CodeIgniter in order to query database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework and I need to create a page that will query mysql database to retrieve events, and then echo the results back using json_encode like this: `echo json_encode($events);`

In order to be able to query the database using `$qryEvents = $this->db->query("SELECT ...`, I need to put the page in an accessible location, that also has access to the database library (which is autoloaded by config/autoload.php).  My question is:  In what folder should the page be located?  I tried to place the page in the application/views folder, but when I tried to look at that page directly in the browser, I got an error:

```
You don't have permission to access /application/views/myfeed.php on this server
```

I need to figure out what the correct path would be to use in the following code which initializes the fullCalendar jQuery plugin:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventSources: [
    {
        url:  '/application/views/myfeed.php',  <-- WHAT IS CORRECT PATH TO USE???
        color: '#DBBE00',     
        textColor: '#000000' 
    }
],    
theme: true,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: false
});
```

The code above does not work because I cannot access a view directly.  Where should I put the `myfeed.php` file, and what is the correct URL to access the file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question I discovered by realizing that it was not a "view" that needed to be loaded, but rather it was simply a calculation, or method, if you will.  All I had to do was to move the calculation code that was in myfeed.php and put it into a controller and then a method.  After I did that, it was simply a matter of updating the url parameter as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventSources: [
{
    url:  '/myController/myMethod',  <-- THIS WORKS !!
    color: '#DBBE00',     
    textColor: '#000000' 
}
],    
theme: true,
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: false
});
```

Happy to report that I managed to figure this one out myself.